# Powershell edit HKLM registry with alternate credentials

Tags: powershell, registry

Trying to use Set-ItemProperty to set a HKLM registry using alternate admin credentials, but I am getting an error, "The provider does not support the use of credentials." while running this script as a standard end user who will not have write access to the HKLM value we want to edit.

```
$RegKey1 ='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Workshare.Client.OutlookFormUI.AddinModule'

$username = "LocalAdmin"
$password = "Passw0rd"
$AdminCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey1 -Name "LoadBehavior" -Value 2 -Credential $AdminCred
```

Comment: Use `runas` or `start-process` with alternate credentials, then launch your script in the new process. (There are IIRC other solutions)

Comment: @Vesper I ended up creating a reg file with the desired registry changes in HKLM and used `start-process` reg.exe with the `-credentials` to import the registry file.  Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a reg file with all the desired HKLM changes in it and use start-process with -credentials parameter to execute reg.exe.

```
$username = "mydomain\localdmin"
$password = "Passw0rd"
$AdminCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$regFile = "\\myServer\myShare\myRegFile.reg"
$regArg1 = "import $regFile"

Start-Process reg.exe -ArgumentList $regArg1 -Credential $AdminCred
```

Answer (score -1):

From Get-Help Set-ItemProperty -Detailed:

> -Credential  Specifies a user account that has permission to perform this action. The default is the current user.
>
> Type a user name, such as "User01" or "Domain01\User01", or enter a
>   PSCredential object, such as one generated by the Get-Credentia l
>   cmdlet. If you type a user name, you will be prompted for a password.
>
> **This parameter is not supported by any providers installed with
>   Windows PowerShell.**

Get-PSProvider | FT -AutoSize

```
Name        Capabilities                       Drives
----        ------------                       ------
Registry    ShouldProcess, Transactions        {HKLM, HKCU}
Alias       ShouldProcess                      {Alias}
Environment ShouldProcess                      {Env}
FileSystem  Filter, ShouldProcess, Credentials {C, D, E}
Function    ShouldProcess                      {Function}
Variable    ShouldProcess                      {Variable}
Certificate ShouldProcess                      {Cert}
```

( FileSystem provider has 'Credentials' capabilities since PS 3.0 )

So as you can see, Registry provider doesn't support Credentials. This parameter is only for other custom providers which will use Set-ItemProperty universal command and could potentially add 'Credentials' support for their own way of connecting to remote computers.

If you want to achieve you goal, use PS Remoting, WMI, Remote Registry PowerShell Module or Jerry Lai suggestion.

Comment: OP is using registry, not file system. Registry does not have Credentials capability as per your example above. I didn't notice this and just spent 30 minutes trying to figure out why it wasn't working.